# Kotlin val initialization using when

Tags: initialization, kotlin, field, final

Using Java I may want to initialize a final variable using a switch statement:

```
final String finalValue;

switch (condition) {
   case 1:
      finalValue = "One";
      break;
   case 2:
      finalValue = "Two";
      break;
   case 3:
      finalValue = "Three";
      break;
   default:
      finalValue = "Undefined";
      break;
}
```

In Kotlin, trying to do the same:

```
val finalValue: String

when (condition) {
   1 -> finalValue = "One"
   2 -> finalValue = "Two"
   3 -> finalValue = "Three"
   else -> finalValue = "Undefined"
}
```

result in a compilation error.
A solutions is using the `by lazy` combination, but this create a new `Lazy` instance.

```
val finalValue: String by lazy {    
   when (condition) {
      1 -> "One"
      2 -> "Two"
      3 -> "Three"
      else -> "Undefined"
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: `result in a compilation error` > Specify the compilation error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this construction:

```
    val finalValue: String = when (condition) {
        1 -> "One"
        2 -> "Two"
        3 -> "Three"
        else -> "Undefined"
    }
```

Using [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) as an expression.

Comment: Ahhh damn. I forgot in Kotlin just about everything is an expression. Thus when is "assignable". Thanks for the remainder.

Comment: `: String` is optional in this case. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **init** block to initialize a final variable.

```
val finalValue: String

init {
    finalValue = when (condition) {
        1 -> "One"
        2 -> "Two"
        3 -> "Three"
        else -> "Undefined"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the following does compile, I'm not sure which problem you encountered?

```
fun x(condition: Int = 5) {
    val finalValue: String

    when (condition) {
        1 -> finalValue = "One"
        2 -> finalValue = "Two"
        3 -> finalValue = "Three"
        else -> finalValue = "Undefined"
    }
}
```

The only possibility to me: You wrote the `when` clause into a class body directly, which certainly does not work. You could put it into an `init` block though.

But of course it's much nicer to simply use the power of `when` expression here (Which the IDE also suggests):

```
val finalValue = when (condition) {
    1 -> "One"
    2 -> "Two"
    3 -> "Three"
    else -> "Undefined"
}
```

Comment: Understood. I did not correctly specify the assignment on the "else" branch.